# How do I check if the user is authenticated using anonymous provider

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an Android app, I would like to know how can I get the user login method.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect whether the user is anonymous by checking the [`isAnonymous()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#isAnonymous()) of their user profile.

So:

```
if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().isAnonymous()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try this <3